# cin.getline() is not working as expected

Tags: c++, getline, cin

Can't we use cin.getline() inside a loop? I'm running the following code:

```
for(int k=0; k<t; k++)
{
    char ph1[1000], ph2[1000], ph11[1000], ph22[1000][1000];
    int i, j, count = 0;

    cin.getline(ph1, 1000);
    cin.getline(ph2, 1000);
}
```

The code is supposed to accept two strings (or char *) through cin.getline(). But when I run it, it accepts the first string, prints "NO" and exits. Why is it so? Why is the second cin.getline() being skipped?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you inter the strings? What strings do you enter? By the way, this code has a lot memory leaks.

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::string`?

Comment: You could at least output the strings... It's kinda strange to start asking questions before you actually check what was read in.

Comment: Never mix the stdio functions with streams. They use completely different buffering, so the `fflush` will not do anything to the buffers of `cin`.

Comment: Delete code until it starts working as you'd expect. Then start adding back lines until it doesn't. Then post your question if necessary.

Comment: @KirilKirov: I have to enter two strings containing spaces. I tried with some inputs now. The output is:

2
s,dk gkjsdl dfkjas 0001
NO
NO
sdkjskj djshk sdfkj 0001
smd dfjk 001
NO
NO

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: It's acting the same after removing    fflush()

Comment: Another thing, you do lots of allocations inside the loop, but you never free anything before the loop end, so you will end up with lots of memory leaks.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I want to use strtok(). It won't accept strings, hence, using char *.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: When I free the memory using delete, I am getting "double free or corruption error". Hence, removed those.

Comment: Never call `fflush` on `stdin` - aside from the fact that you shouldn't be mixing C and C++ I/O, calling `fflush` on `stdin` (or any input stream) is evil. See `man fflush`.

Comment: @minoz: *Please* return to square one. Your code is very, very badly broken before you even **get** to `getline()`. You quite obviously are *very* confused on the subject of allocating memory (possibly coming from a Java background?), and even if you get `getline()` to work as you expected (or rather, adjust your expectations to reality), you are bound for a world **full** of pain if you don't get your memory management straightened out. (Hint: `char ph1[1000]; char ph11[1000][1000];` -- certainly *no* "new in a loop".)

Comment: Also: why are you using C strings in a C++ program ?

Comment: @DevSolar: Could you please tell me why it is broken? Well, I haven't used C/C++ since a while and have kinda forgotten a lot. Could you please enlighten me?

Comment: Almost all of the code has nothing to do with the question. Trim out the parts that don't contribute to the problem, and add back the parts that you removed that keep the code from compiling. In short: post a minimal example that compiles and runs and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @PeteBecker: My question is only about the cin.getline() part. I just want to know why it is not accepting the second string.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said: almost all of the code has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @minoz: You still didn't answer the question about how you enter the strings. In one line, space delimited? In seperate lines, pushing ENTER after each string? -0.5 for not providing an SSCCE ( http://www.sscce.org), and -0.5 for not answering the relevant questions. I would give another -1 for the `new` massacre going on...

Comment: @DevSolar: Extremely sorry. I am giving strings having spaces in them as inputs, e.g., "I am minoz" and pushing ENTER after each string.

Comment: @All: Or can anybody tell me the way to accept strings containing spaces?

Comment: @minoz: Between your initial memory massacre and the displayed inability for basic debugging techniques (like checking assumptions, testing of sub-parts of a program for expected results etc.), I repeat my plea: Return to square one. You apparently have much to (re-)learn, and shouldn't press on towards solving your current problem. You are building on a foundation of quicksand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after you edited it, your example code **still** doesn't compile. It's a loop without surrounding `main()`.

I rewrote it to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    char ph1[1000], ph2[1000];

    std::cin.getline(ph1, 1000);
    std::cin.getline(ph2, 1000);

    std::cout << "ph1: '" << ph1 << "' - ph2: '" << ph2 << "'" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This works as expected, i.e. the problem you perceive has nothing to do with "cin.getline() not working", and is not exhibited by the code you posted. Voting for closing the question.

Comment: DevSolar: The code you gave is also not accepting the strings properly inside the loop. Anyway, I cut the part of main() because I thought it wouldn't matter as my question was about getline().

Comment: This is a very poor example. An unchecked input operation is essentially a programming error.

Comment: @minoz - the code that DevSolar posted does not have a loop. But start from there, and build up to something more like the code you're having problems with. This is a standard debugging technique: get down to something simple that works, and work back up toward the more complex code that doesn't work. I often find that I solve the problem in the course of trying to write code suitable for posting on a forum like this.

Comment: @minoz: The code works perfectly even if placed in a loop. Since you didn't tell or show us what is *expected* of the loop, and I am not psychic, I cannot tell what exactly is *not* working for you.

Comment: @KerrekSB: This is a minimal modification of the OP's own example. I am not willing to do full-blown error checking and code-style massaging on proof-of-concept code snippets, and I would thank you for not stalking me for it.

Comment: @DevSolar: Unfortunately, there are just so many posts on SO concerning I/O which would have been moot had the posters done the proper error checks. More practically, we can't see user input, so we're at the mercy of users reporting correctly the circumstances that made their code "stop working", and that's never a good place to be in. Basically, this is one of the most egregious cases of bad practice, exacerbated by countless instances of bad examples. Even if it's what the OP wrote, I feel that this cannot make enough of an effort to set this bad habit right. (And it's nothing personal!)

Comment: @KerrekSB: The "right" amount of error checking etc. depends on context. If you go the whole way, C++ strings and exception safety and const correctness and everything, you get berated for non-minimal example, inappropriateness in embedded systems, or needless complexity. (Been there, got the downvotes to prove it.) More importantly though, I feel that the OP is *already* stretching the limits of his understanding, and didn't want to confuse him further by pressing too many things on him at once (and then having to explain to him how to do `strtok()` on a C++ `string`)...

Answer (score 0):

You *may* want something like this:

```
for (std::string l1, l2;
     std::getline(std::cin, l1) && std::getline(std::cin, l2); )
{
    std::cout << "Your first line: '" << l1
              << "'\nYour second line: '" << l2 << "'\n";
}
```

You should *always* consider it a hard programming and logic error if you perform an input operation whose return value is not immediately used in a boolean context. In my example, the condition check of the `for` loop tests whether two successive line extractions succeeded, and if not (e.g. if the file stream has reached the end), the loop breaks.

Comment: Can I downvote this because it doesn't show the appropriate `#include` statements and `main()` function? That's an error too.